# how can i create a html file template in django application?

Tags: django

I'm learning Django and I have a  problem that there is no answer for it on internet
here is the problem,
I created a folder as 'app', and I create another folder in app as 'challenges' (in VS Code in a Django application),
so we have 2 nested folders
now I want to create an HTML page, and I create a file as 'index.html',
but VS Code cannot know this file as an HTML file

Comment: create a folder in 'challenges' called 'templates', and in that 'templates' folder create another folder called challenges. Or Create a 'templates' folder on the same level as 'challenges. Put your html templates in there. See https://learndjango.com/tutorials/template-structure for a good overview.

Comment: i created my folder and file just like this but i do not know why vscode cannot know my html file

Comment: Does it have an html extension?

Answer (score 0):

You need to make a folder structure like this

```
>app_name
>>...
>>templates
>>>app_name
>>>>index.html
```

views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render

def index(request):
   return render(request, 'app_name/index.html)
```

urls.py

```
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.index),
]
```